# Powershell script - view O365 licenses

Tags: powershell

I have two scripts which each show half what I want but unsure how to merge.

running below script

```
Get-MsolAccountSku | 
Select-Object -Property AccountSkuId,@{
Name = 'Spare Licenses'
Expression = $spare
}
```

Is the layout which I want
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UbXN.png)

But I only want the following two to be shown as per script below

```
Get-MsolAccountSku | 
Select-Object -Property AccountSkuId,@{
Name = 'Spare Licenses'
Expression = $spare
}
```

So it looks like this
[Result required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1rjM.png)

If possible but NOT required even shorting name to exclude the xxxx in xxxx.O365_BUSINESS_ESEENTIALS

I have also tried to have the result in popup window using

```
#$ButtonType = [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::OK
```

for example. So if you have complete code with a pop up window that would be great.

Comment: `Where-Object` is your friend: `Get-MsolAccountSku |Where-Object { $_.AccountSkuId -like 'xxxx:O365_BUSINESS_*'} |Select-Object ...`

Comment: Thank you. This worked as follows: Get-MsolAccountSku |Where-Object { $_.AccountSkuId -like 'XXXXX:O365_BUSINESS_*'} |Select-Object -Property AccountSkuId,@{
    Name = 'Spare Licenses'
    Expression = $spare
}

Comment: Excellent, you should post an answer below! :)

Answer (score 0):

As per help above managed to get working using following script

```
$Licenses = Get-MsolAccountSku 
$spare = { $_.ActiveUnits - $_.ConsumedUnits }
Get-MsolAccountSku |Where-Object { $_.AccountSkuId -like 'XXXXX:O365_BUSINESS_*'} |Select-Object -Property AccountSkuId,@{
    Name = 'SpareLicenses'
    Expression = $spare
}
```